# Adjust max children with php-fpm

Tags: php, apache

I have a webserver running out of memory regularly, because of too many php5-cgi processes.
So I am trying to limit their number, and I have pm.max_children = 5 in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf but it does not work : I sometimes have 30+ php5-cgi
How can I achieve this ?

I run : Debian 3.16.39-1, Apache/2.4.10, PHP Version 5.6.30 with php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

Actually I thought I was using php-fpm, but due to a configuration error Fcgi was still being used (that's why I had php5-cgi processes).

After really switching to php-fpm (see [How to really enable php-fpm with apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702074/how-to-really-enable-php-fpm-with-apache)), pm.max_children worked by limiting the number of php processes