# How to really enable php-fpm with apache?

Tags: php, apache

I installed apache2.4 and php-fpm, but I still have php5-cgi processing my requests, althought php-fpm process is running.

Here is what I did :

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
a2enmod actions
```

Edit /etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf like that :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header  Authorization
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
Require all granted
</Directory>
</IfModule>

service apache2 restart
```

But now if I run phpinfo() I get :

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

instead of FPM/FastCGI

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found why php fpm wasn't used :
I needed to enable it in my vhost files. Edit :

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.conf

remove :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/domain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
```

add :

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/home/domain/domains/domain/public_html/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

another try:

Install the Apache Worker MPM (Multi-Procesing Modules)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5-fpm php5
sudo apt-get update
```

and again:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5-fpm php5

sudo a2enmod actions fastcgi alias
```

restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then `sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf` and paste that in:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
    #directory statement mult be on multiple lines
</IfModule>
```

then :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and that should work

Comment: a2enconf php5-fpm : ERROR: Conf php5-fpm does not exist!
And php5 is installed

Comment: So try to `apt-get install php5-fpm` again.

Comment: Would you please `service apache2 reload` and try again.

Comment: if your apache2 server `apache2 -version`  is 2.3 or older then check if you have `/etc/apache2/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf` file? if not create one and paste this line inside `<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin> Require all granted </Directory>` then restart your server again.

Comment: I have apache 2.4 and /etc/apache2/conf.d/ does not exist. So I created this directory, and the file inside it, restarted apache, and I still get the same error : a2enconf php5-fpm
ERROR: Conf php5-fpm does not exist!

Comment: no i said if your server version is `2.3` or older. delete this folder and i will post the whole process and try it again.

Comment: Ok I did everything you said in your updated answer, no error, but still : Server API CGI/FastCGI, and php5-cgi processes

Comment: one last try `a2dismod php5` and restart your server

Comment: Module php5 already disabled. And after the server reboot I still have CGI/FastCGI

Comment: so you still dont have `php5-fpm`

Comment: Still not. And I have no idea why, all your commands were successfull

Comment: Did you change your answer again ? Now it says "/etc/apache2/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf" and this folder does not exists for me